# Android apk differentiation

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk

I load an apk created in Eclipse Android Java bin, which works fine. However, I want to make a slight change and also load the resulting apk on the same machine along with the original version. What do I have to change to make the Android tablet see two different apks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the package name of the second app. You cannot have two apps installed at the same time with the same package name.

Comment: So I have to refactor and recompile the whole thing?

Comment: @DirkBruere: You have to change the `package` attribute in the manifest. That, in turn, will require you to fix up your `R` references. Whether you choose to refactor the rest of your classes to the new package (or simply update the manifest to point to the proper fully-qualified class names) is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you just need to change the package name in the manifest, but I would suggest that you change also the app name so you can identify which is what.